# Appium scroll action happening twice

Tags: java, ios, selenium, automation, appium

I'm using below code to scroll the screen on an iOS device, but its scrolling twice. I have multiple elements in the screen with the same name, but i want to scroll to the first element.

```
 JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
         HashMap<String, String> scrollObject = new HashMap<String, String>();
         scrollObject.put("direction", "down");
         scrollObject.put("xpath", "//XCUIElementTypeStaticText[@name='Max threshold (L/s)']");
         js.executeScript("mobile: scroll", scrollObject);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add sequence number to your `xpath`:

```
scrollObject.put("xpath", "(//XCUIElementTypeStaticText[@name='Max threshold (L/s)'])[1]");
```

Comment: Still it scroll twice, it's not stopping at the target element. Is there any way where i can scroll till the target element of an iOS app.

Comment: I used below code, and it was working fine for me.

public void verticalSwipeOnce(double scrollPercentageStart, double scrollPecentageEnd) {

  Dimension dim = driver.manage().window().getSize();

  int height = dim.getHeight();
  int starty = (int) (height * scrollPercentageStart);
  int endy = (int) (height * scrollPecentageEnd);
  new TouchAction((PerformsTouchActions) (driver)).press(PointOption.point(0, starty))
    .waitAction(WaitOptions.waitOptions(Duration.ofMillis(1000))).moveTo(PointOption.point(0, endy))
    .release().perform();

 }

Comment: @cindy87 Just suggest, if that solved your problem, please post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Below code helped me,

```
public void verticalSwipeOnce(double scrollPercentageStart, double scrollPecentageEnd) {

Dimension dim = driver.manage().window().getSize();
int height = dim.getHeight(); int starty = (int) (height * scrollPercentageStart);
int endy = (int) (height * scrollPecentageEnd);
new TouchAction((PerformsTouchActions) (driver)).press(PointOption.point(0, starty)) .waitAction(WaitOptions.waitOptions(Duration.ofMillis(1000))).moveTo(PointOption.point(0, endy)) .release().perform();

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add:

```
params.put("duration","1");
```

This should ensure that it will scroll one time